# I need information about writing a device driver for microcontroller

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, microcontroller

i am bit confused between device driver and source code. what is the necessity of device driver.for eg. suppose i want to interface LPC2148 to LCD so do i need to develop driver for it?? or i need to write only a source code.

When it is required to write device driver for microcontroller. 
and what is meant by linux device driver? do i need to port linux kernel in microcontroller?

is there any resource on internet, or any book from which i can learn these all things?

Thank you friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Source code and device driver are two different things..
2. device drivers required for controlling the device ...in case of micro-controller device drivers are used for accessing registers, bit wise functionality and ports in general...
3. source code can be for any software -written in low or high level language.
4. on the question of device driver-- many times driver is provided in linux or available from device manufacturer...u don't need to write device driver unless u r a developer or making a project...
5. there are many resources available on the internet for interfacing any micro-controller with lcd...just google it..
   hope this helps...

cheers and regards  dip-ak